# react project compiles but not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gulp, nodemon

I am on my reactjs project. I run gulp command to compile the project. During compile i get few errors and still the project compiles succcessfully. But I am not able to run my application. I am sure it is because of compile errors.

This is my compile console

```
Apurvs-MacBook-Pro:tessact-client-2 apurvgandhwani$ gulp
[01:52:51] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[01:52:51] Requiring external module babel-register
[01:52:54] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/gulpfile.babel.js
[01:52:54] Starting 'build:watch'...
[01:52:54] Starting 'copy:assets'...
[01:52:54] Starting 'copy:vendors'...
  Cleaned build/ 
  Copied 14 asset entries.
[01:52:54] Finished 'copy:vendors' after 157 ms
[01:52:54] Starting 'copy:views'...
[01:52:54] copied views all files 1.79 kB
[01:52:54] Finished 'copy:views' after 60 ms
[01:52:54] Starting 'copy:public'...
[01:52:54] Finished 'copy:public' after 29 ms
[01:52:54] Finished 'copy:assets' after 248 ms
[01:52:54] Starting 'bundle:dll'...
DLL Bundled.
Hash: 0c28a0c5268f8a4b023c
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 2362ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
dll.vendor.js  3.16 MB       0  [emitted]  vendor
[01:52:57] Finished 'bundle:dll' after 2.4 s
[01:52:57] Starting 'bundle'...
Hash: d2622522a127e8235b84
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 641ms
           Asset   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server-bundle.js  65 kB       0  [emitted]  main
  -- server:watch bundled.
Hash: b86595a12c8058d77ded
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 6049ms
                               Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
00103e881a36640a08f869ff6888f0fd.eot   5.9 kB          [emitted]  
                      main-bundle.js  3.13 MB       0  [emitted]  main
  -- client bundled.
[01:53:03] Finished 'bundle' after 6.05 s
[01:53:03] Starting 'start:server'...
Starting Node Server...
[01:53:03] Finished 'start:server' after 147 ms
[01:53:03] Starting 'watch:sync'...
[01:53:03] [nodemon] 1.14.11
[01:53:03] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[01:53:03] [nodemon] watching: build/server-bundle.js
[01:53:03] [nodemon] starting `node --debug --inspect build/server-bundle.js`
Server Restarted: Reloading BrowserSync.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/c6e6fdcb-9801-4097-b9cb-7480c39f4380
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[tessact: ] Proxying: http://localhost:4200
[tessact: ] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.32:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.32:3001
 -------------------------------------
[tessact: ] Watching files...
[01:53:03] Finished 'watch:sync' after 224 ms
[01:53:03] Starting 'watch:assets'...
[01:53:03] Finished 'watch:assets' after 14 ms
[01:53:03] Finished 'build:watch' after 9.09 s
[01:53:03] Starting 'default'...
[01:53:03] Finished 'default' after 28 μs
  tessact:db DBERROR:  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 +0ms
ServerStartupError:  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1194:14)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at /Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/src/server/db.js:26:14
From previous event:
    at initDB (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/src/server/db.js:25:9)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/src/server/app.js:27:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/server-bundle.js:48:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:19:1)
    at /Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:39:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/tessact-client-2/tessact-client-2/build/server-bundle.js:44:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
[tessact: ] Reloading Browsers...
[01:53:05] [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
webpack built b86595a12c8058d77ded in 3199ms
Hash: b86595a12c8058d77ded
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 3199ms
                               Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
00103e881a36640a08f869ff6888f0fd.eot   5.9 kB          [emitted]  
                      main-bundle.js  3.13 MB       0             main
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

There is an error in the starting and one in the middle of the snippet.

This is my config.js file

```
const IS_PROD = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
// const IS_PROD = false;

const NODE_PORT = 4211;
const BS_PORT   = 3002;

module.exports = {
    NODE_PORT,
    BS_PORT,

    SESSION_SECRET: 't355@c7_S3cr37',

    LOGIN_URL: "https://www.backend.trigger.tessact.com/auth/login/",

    DB: {
        production: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'tessact_db' 
        },
        development: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3306,
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'tessact_db'
        }
    },

    ACL_POPULATION_URL: '/populate',
    ACL_UPDATE_URL: '/update-acl-population'

}
```

This is my configure.js file

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import logger from 'morgan'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import compression from 'compression'

import session from 'express-session'

import config from './config'
import getRoutes from './routes'

const IS_PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export default function configureServer(db, app){
    const loggerMode = IS_PROD ? 'combined' : 'dev'
    const env = IS_PROD ? 'production' : 'development'

    const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session)

    app.set('env', env);
    app.use(logger(loggerMode));

    // Pretty prints template output
    if (!IS_PROD) {
        app.locals.pretty = true;
    }

    // Where to find templates
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');


    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(compression());

    // Server static assets from this directory
    app.use('/public', 
        express.static( path.resolve(__dirname, './public'))
    );

    // Should come after static assets
    // Otherwise static requests will be treated with cookies and session as well
    app.use(cookieParser(config.SESSION_SECRET));
    app.use(
        session({
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
            store: new MySQLStore({}, db)
        })
    )


    // Add routes
    app.use('/', getRoutes(db, app));

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    // error handlers


    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            res.status(err.status || 500);
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });

    return Promise.resolve({db, app})
}
```

This is my db.js

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import config from './config';
import mysql from 'mysql';



var debug = require('debug')('tessact:db');
const IS_PROD = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production");

const connOptions = config.DB[
    IS_PROD ? 'production' : 'development'
]

var connection = mysql.createConnection(connOptions)

process.on('SIGTERM', ()=> {
    connection.end(err=> {
        if (error){
            console.error(err);
        }
        debug('DB Closed');
    })
});

const initDB = ()=> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        connection.connect(err => {
            if (err){
                debug('DBERROR: ', err.message)
                return reject(err)
            }
            debug('Connected')
            resolve(connection)
        })
    });
}

export default initDB;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application fails to connect to the database (I assume mysql). It tries to connect to localhost:3306 and gets `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` which usually means there is no mysql listening on this server.

You should either start mysql on the same machine, or configure your application to connect to a remote mysql.

It is also possible that you have a database running but listening on a different port or network-interface.

Comment: Ideally this should run. I never got these errors earlier. And why " Failed to load external module @babel/register" this is there?

Comment: Please have a look at the extra things I added.

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/356 
try to `npm install` again

Comment: and did you restart your mysql?

Comment: How to restart?

Comment: I am still getting the same errors even after doing npm install again. Are the files I added in update are correct?

Comment: And I already followed that github thread and have babel-core instead of babel in my package.json. Still I am getting that babel error

Comment: try this for mysql help: https://serverfault.com/questions/69507/can-anyone-tell-me-why-my-web-server-cannot-connect-to-a-db-server

Comment: If your using MAMP make sure the mysql port is `3306` and not something different. Go to `Preferences > Ports > MySqlPort` and the port should be set to 3306 as requested by your app.